# Localization in nopcommerce

Tags: localization, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I change language on nopcommerce and in admin panel and when i'am log in is all ok..but when unknown user visit my site, they see onlu tags. You see this when you are logged into the system [IMAGE](http://i57.tinypic.com/r8dmci.png) and this is what user see when he is not loged in [IMAGE](http://i57.tinypic.com/2ut3sit.png) You cna see differences you can see in the fist top menu [log in, wishlist, cart..].

I try to change language in menu configuration>language>..
And i try to import new language too.. but always i have that problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the language you have chosen doesn't have entries for those resources.  You can add them manually in Admin -> Configuration -> Languages -> the language and then add a record for each using that tag as the ResourceName.

Answer (score 1):

I just follow these steps to change language on nopcommerce and they worked fine for me :-

- go to Configuration → Languages.
- To add a new language, click Add new. In the Add a new language
  window.
- Fill all the fields :-

  1.The Name of the new language.

  2.The Language culture — a specific language code
  (Eg- (France). fr-FR etc.)

  ```
  When updating the Language culture field, please make sure the 
  appropriate CLDR package is installed for this culture. You can 
  set CLDR for the specified culture in the Localization panel of 
  the Configuration → Settings → General Settings page.
  ```

  [Localization settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr62x.png)

  3. The Unique SEO code —  two-letter language SEO code(Eg- fr).
  4. The Flag image file name — enter the flag image file name. Which
     is saved under the …/images/flags directory.
  5. Select Right-to-Left if needed (eg- Arabic or
     Hebrew).
  6. Select the Default currency for a specific language.
  7. Limited to stores option allowing to set this language for a
     specific store(s).
  8. Publish the language to enable it to be visible and selected by
     visitors to your store.
  9. Display order of the language.(Eg 1 top of the list).

  Here is the screen shot of add new language :-

  [AddNewLanguage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCY1G.png)

4. After adding a new language, you will be able to import and export
   string resources using the Import resources and Export resources
   buttons at the top of the page. The String resources panel on the
   language edit page will allow you to view the existing language
   resources and add new ones manually.

   Click on Save button to save the langauge.
5. After saving the new language, if you refresh the page you can see a
   dropdown at the top of the banner in Admin panel and if you navigate
   to the Public store you can also see it below the Administration
   but if u select that language from the dropdown it will show you
   only the Resource Name not the value for that you need to import the
   language pack.

[Without Importing language Pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmPk6.png)

Import language pack

1. Download the language pack from :-
   https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/translations
2. Choose the nopCommerce version and download the desired language
   pack.
3. After that click on the Edit button beside that language in the
   Language List page.
4. Click Import resources on the top of the Edit page or you can see
   it during the add new language after click on the  save and
   continue button. And specify the path to the language pack
   file (*.xml) that you downloaded and click on Import Resources
   button.

   NOTE: It can take up to several minutes.
5. After sucessfully Import of the file you can check the resources for
   that language in the String Resources or you can simply search for
   that resource after click on string resource at the bottom of the
   info tab by the Resource Name or value.

   [String resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmSQD.png)
6. Just select the language that you want from the dropdown and it
   will look like this

   [After Importing Language Pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1478.png)

Follow this link to see more about how to add new language.

https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/getting-started/advanced-configuration/localization.html

Hope this Help.